# Reviews Grid Listing, Reviews Edit Form and Reviews New Form are not showing in admin Magento2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2.2, product-review

> After logged in admin I can't see reviews listing. Also in product edit page in admin review listing not showing. Any one know what is the solution?

[image]

Log File Showing Error Below

> [2018-07-24 06:25:27] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://localhost/magento2/admin/review/product/index/key/33716591056fa74ee620fcd6424973062b37f27da9b6fe33cc1bcab69a9e5ba0/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []
>
> [2018-07-24 06:30:49] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http:/","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["interception","CONFIG"],"mode":"matchingTag"}} []

Comment: Can you check console and log?

Comment: Please check Log Showing Above!

Comment: https://github.com/A-1A/Magento2-Issues/issues/1

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/17165