# Existing updates grid is not showing

Tags: magento2

I am using Magento Enterprise 2.2.2. In admin panel
Catalog -> Categories -> Select any Category -> Schedule New Updates -> Assign to Existing Update

Here it should show already existed updates grid but it showing nothing. I have searched on Google but did not find any solution. If you have any idea then can you please share it with me?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235681/reviews-grid-listing-reviews-edit-form-and-reviews-new-form-are-not-showing-in

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235727/review-and-rating-not-working-in-admin-and-frontend-in-magento2

Comment: Also please check if anyone found solution please answer above questions

Answer (score 0):

Just clear your browser cache or open it in the incognito.